# MobileFirst 7.0 SSL Handshake issues

Tags: javascript, https, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

I have a MobileFirst Platform 7.0 javascript adapter that is connecting to a HTTPS endpoint. I have connected to this endpoint directly with Android, iOS, and Windows using a p12 certificate file and it connects without any errors. However, I can't seem to do the same thing with a HTTP javascript adapter on the MobileFirst Platform  server.

Anyway, how can I do this? I have exported the entire contents of the p12 into a java keystore and also imported the certificate from the server and also added that into the java keystore. However, I keep getting the below error:

`Authentication failure in realm 'CustomAuthenticationRealm':    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Further, my javascript adapter is connecting to the local jks with the below alias and password configuration:

```
`<sslCertificateAlias>my alias</sslCertificateAlias>
<sslCertificatePassword>my password</sslCertificatePassword>`
```

My worklight.properties is also setup like the below:
    `ssl.keystore.path=conf/mykeystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.type=jks
    ssl.keystore.password=mypassword`

Any information is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you added the backend's certificate to your server's truststore?. Do you intend to use mutual SSL authentication

Comment: I added the certificate to the keystore that is assigned in worklight.properties. Is there another trust store I am supposed to use? If so, where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. Apparently, when making secure connections from javascript adapters from MFP, there can be the potential for 2 locations on where a certificate needs to be installed. One is in the key.jks in the server directory and the other in the custom keystore created that is referenced in worklight.properties.